# How to install specific python version in virtual environment on Mac without pyenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

My Mac has python 3.10.5, and I have created a virtual environment which has python 3.8.5, now I want to create another virtual environment with python 3.7, I have searched online for a while, most ppl would suggest using `pyenv`, but I am pretty sure my python 3.8.5 virtual environment is installed without `pyenv`, I only used `virtualenv`.

---

```
sky@Skys-MBP ~ % python -V
Python 3.10.5
sky@Skys-MBP ~ % cd environments 
sky@Skys-MBP environments % ls
bin     coursera    lib     python3.8env    pyvenv.cfg  screenshots share
sky@Skys-MBP environments % source python3.8env/bin/activate
(python3.8env) sky@Skys-MBP environments % python -V
Python 3.8.5
(python3.8env) sky@Skys-MBP environments % deactivate
sky@Skys-MBP environments %
```

Comment: Install the Python version you want to have and `/path/to/your/python/binary -m venv ...`.

Comment: @KlausD. How do I install python in at specific folder only ?

Comment: You need to install Python globally. You can install as many Python interpreters as you want. -- "Installing in a specific folder only" is not a concept that exists for Python, as far as I know. But for sure there must be some extra additional tooling somewhere that might help get in that direction. -- Not sure if `pyenv` can help you here for your specific use cases, you should try it. -- Anyway, the sure thing is that `virtualenv` requires the Python interpreter to be installed and operational beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. find out the path where your python version is installed
2. run below

   virtualenv -p /your/python/path/python2.6 foldernamehere

Comment: If you really ended up with Python 2.6, you are in for a world of hurt.

Comment: just an example, LOL